# Interdependent Class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Say class A depends on Class B and via versa.

So obviously in a.h I would put #import"b.h" and in "b.h" I would import "a.h"

After that

Should we

declare @class A

in b.h AND @class B in a.h

Should we do both or should we use @class only once?

Why?

I reasoned that if I do it only once, say including @class B in a.h, given that a.h also contains #import "b.h" then the class a.h already knows about b.h

However it seems that I got to do it both in xcode and I wonder why.

Comment: Why is there a circular dependency?

Comment: +1 to BoltClock: the way to resolve this issue isn't to import both, but to figure out why there is a circular dependency and fix it.

Comment: @dlev, your comment implies that having two classes that refer to each other is necessarily a problem. But that sort of situation happens all the time. Example: most relationships between entities in Core Data should have inverse relationships. If each entity in such a relationship is a different class, those classes will probably refer to each other. Most sufficiently complex data models are not directed acyclic graphs. If it were always possible to avoid circular references, we wouldn't need forward declarations in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a forward declaration (i.e. `@class Foo`) in the header file for each class. You can do that if all you need is for each class to reference the other. A forward declaration just tells the compiler "This name refers to a class, and the actual declaration of the class will come later."

As you say, you could also use a forward declaration of B in A.h, and then just import A.h in B.h. I don't think there's any real benefit to doing that unless there are other things in A.h that you also need to reference in B.h.

> However it seems that I got to do it
>   both in xcode and I wonder why.

If you mean that you're getting an error when you import A.h in B.h instead of using a forward declaration of A, please post the error. I don't think there should be a problem with that. (And in any case, the issue would be a compiler issue or an Objective-C issue, not an Xcode problem. Xcode is just the IDE.)

Comment: I guess I should just give up figuring this out. It's working anyway after I put forward declaration on both .h files.

Comment: @Jim Thio, I suppose "one works and the other doesn't" is a reasonable way to choose one over the other. Still, forward-referencing B in A.h and importing A.h in B.h should be fine... do you get an error of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink your design, a circular dependency like this should not be needed.

What you probably want is to declare `ClassA` and `ClassADelegate` in `ClassA.h`. Next up declare `ClassB` in `ClassB.h`, and import `ClassA.h` from there, let `ClassB` conform to `ClassADelegate` protocol to resolve the circular dependency.

This way you get a clear ownership relation, and code that will be much easier to maintain and extend in the future.

Comment: So say you've got Person and Vehicle classes. Person has a 'vehicle' property which points to an instance of Vehicle, and Vehicle has an 'owner' property which points to an instance of Person. Why is this situation sub-optimal? How would you resolve the circular dependency? Why is "clear ownership" needed? And how will your solution be "much easier to maintain and extend"?

Comment: Or, a little less argumentatively ;-) I agree that "clear ownership" simplifies things, but it often doesn't match the necessary data model. In such cases, you just need to be careful about managing the relationship -- e.g. know what to do with a vehicle when a person is deleted and vice versa. Do you really think that forward references are always avoidable?

Comment: Forward declarations serve this precise purpose: to have two class refer each other with no complains from the compiler. I don't get why this is necessarily a bad thing, there some data relationships you can only model this way. Of course when you have a situation like this, one of the class must act as the "owner" , and retains the instance of the other class, while the other is the "child" and simply assigns the instance of the other class.

Comment: @Caleb - In the Owner/Person relationship a forward declaration is probably the right thing to do. Since the Vehicle to Person relation is probably passive, the Vehicle does not depend on functionality from the Person to function.

Comment: @Caleb - In an active relationship such as Vehicle+Engine where none can truly function without the other a clear ownership and separation is probably what you need. Most likely the Engine only knows what it needs from the Vehicle via the EngineDelegate protocol.

Comment: @PeyloW, I agree with both your comments. In the OP's question, we know only that the classes are A and B and that they depend on each other. All I'm saying is that there's nothing wrong that sort of mutual relationship, the mutual dependency may very well be necessary, and it seems like jumping to conclusions to say that the design needs rethinking. Now, if the classes really are called A and B, there are bigger problems... ;-)